# Docker -v mounted to local windows c: sqlserver

Tags: docker, docker-volume

I am spinning up Microsoft SQL server in a Docker container:

```
docker run -e "ACCEPT_EULA=Y" -e "SA_PASSWORD=XXXXXXXXX!" -p 1433:1433 
-v sqldata:/var/opt/mssql   ??C:\mysqldata ??
-d mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest
```

I am missing how to mount -v sqldata:/var/opt/mssql to c:\mysqldata

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it:

```
docker run -e "ACCEPT_EULA=Y" --name SQLEXPRESS 
-e "SA_PASSWORD=XXXXXXXX"  -p 1433:1433  
-v c:\sqldata:/var/opt/mssql/data  
-d mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest
```